# listview duplicate items from query

Tags: c#, sql, list, listview, xamarin

I have a query that is getting from the database duplicate info, I read the data from the query with a datareader, then I add the items to a list that as the type history.

As you can see below from the list, the `index[0]` and `index[1]` have the same date and day, I want a group then and only shown 1 day and 1 date. To show the data I use a grid inside a listview, you guys can see the example below.

Thanks.

**DataReader:*

```
while (dr.Read())
            {


                var history= new Models.History();
                history.Description Article = dr["Description Article"].ToString().TrimEnd();
                history.Date= dr["Data"].ToString().TrimEnd();
                history.Day= dr["Day"].ToString().TrimEnd();
                history.Article = dr["Article"].ToString().TrimEnd();

                listEmentas.Add(history);


            }
```

List with the information:

### [0]

- Date:02-08-2017
- Article:Article Name1
- Day:Monday
- Description Article: Example Description Article.

### [1]

- Date:02-08-2017
- Article:Article Name2
- Day:Monday
- Description Article:Example Description Article.

### [2]

- Date:03-08-2017
- Article:Article Name1
- Day:Tuesday
- Description Article:Example Description Article.

### [3]

- Date:03-08-2017
- Article:Article Name2
- Day:Tuesday
- Description Article:Example Description Article.

Design to show the information:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListviewHistory">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Date}"  ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="5" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Article}" FontAttributes="Bold" ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Day}" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Description}" ></Label>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**History Class:**

```
public class History
{
    public string Day{ get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Description Article { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: use distinct in your query.

Comment: And without changing the query is possible?

Comment: I don't know.. i dont have your data and also how you construct your query

Comment: I don't have the query, I only have stored procedure that returns data, the data is like in the list that i put in the post above.

Comment: You can select the distinct rows from a collection with linq:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property